# Android Debug crash on startup - Release working fine

Tags: react-native

React Native App crashes on Android device in debug mode. Using the release build or debugging on emmulator everything is working fine. Logcat only shows:

"05-09 13:56:13.218 31875 31875 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()" no further messages.

I updated the react version some weeks ago to the newest version but i also did many code changes in the meanwhile and I primary used iOS for debugging so I am not shure which change causes the problem right now. Weeks ago everything was working fine on Android device while debugging.

iOS is working fine in debug and release mode on device and emmulator.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint *.js **/*.js",
    "postinstall": "./fix-rncamera-search-path.sh ./node_modules/react-native-camera/ios/RNCamera.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.3",
    "firebase": "^5.9.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-highlight-words": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "0.0.14",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.21.3",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.7.4",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
    "react-native-maps-super-cluster": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.14.52",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.10.12",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.3",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.4",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
    "eslint": "^5.15.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "jest": "24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
      "jest": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-use-before-define": "off",
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
      "react/prop-types": "off",
      "react/sort-comp": "off",
      "comma-dangle": "off",
      "max-len": [
        "error",
        120
      ],
      "no-else-return": "off"
    },
    "globals": {
      "fetch": false
    }
  }
}
```